# javascript sum up selected element data value and deduct when unselect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have 3 div which are item1, item2, and item3.

item1 with `<data-price="10">`， item1 with `<data-price="20">`， item1 with `<data-price="30">`

What I'm trying to do is when selected the item, it will get the item's `<data-price>` and sum up, while if unselect the selected item, it will remove/deduct the `<data-price>`.

But my code result only shows the selected item  instead of summing up.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="container2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><div id="item1" class="select_itm" data-item="1" data-price="10">Item 1 [Price = 10]</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><div id="item2" class="select_itm" data-item="2" data-price="20">Item 2 [Price = 20]</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><div id="item3" class="select_itm" data-item="3" data-price="30">Item 3 [Price = 30]</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <p>Total Price: <span id="display">0</span></p>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var image_selected = new Array();
  $('#container2').on('click', ".select_itm", function () {
    var aa = $(this)
    if (!aa.is('.checked')){
      aa.addClass('checked'); 
      var myprice = this.getAttribute('data-price');
      image_selected.push(myprice);
    } else {
      aa.removeClass('checked');
      var myprice=this.getAttribute('data-price');
      var index = image_selected.indexOf(myprice);
      if (index > -1) {
        image_selected.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    var price = 0;
    price += image_selected;
    $('#display').html(price);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to use `checked` class to loop through the `checked` elements

- Also `is('.checked')` *may work* but `is(':checked')` works with inputs checkbox/radio and to check for classes you can use `if($(selector).hasClass('checked'))` checked here can be any class you need to check for

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container2').on('click', ".select_itm", function () {
    var aa = $(this), price = 0;
    aa.toggleClass('checked');                   // toggle the class checked on click
    $(".select_itm.checked").each(function(){    // loop through the checked items
      price += parseInt($(this).data('price'));  // get total price of checked items
    });
    $('#display').html(price);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container2">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><div id="item1" class="select_itm" data-item="1" data-price="10">Item 1 [Price = 10]</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><div id="item2" class="select_itm" data-item="2" data-price="20">Item 2 [Price = 20]</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><div id="item3" class="select_itm" data-item="3" data-price="30">Item 3 [Price = 30]</div></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
        <p>Total Price: <span id="display">0</span></p>
</div>
```

Note: **The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer** with `parseInt` `1 + 1 = 2` without it `"1" + "1" = "11"` .. So keep this in mind

Comment: You're totally welcome @LennonGoh .. Have a nice day :-)